# RubyMotion Firebase (motion-firebase) How to retrieve data?

Tags: firebase, rubymotion

Using the motion-firebase library for RubyMotion Firebase (https://github.com/colinta/motion-firebase) I can set data easy enough either by doing:

```
firebase.set({ full_name: ['first_name' => 'Fred', 'last_name' => 'Flintstone'] })
```

or

```
firebase['first_name'] = 'Fred'
```

But I'm having trouble figuring out how to retrieve data.

I've tried the different `firebase.query` methods listed in the reponse readme but I'm definitely missing something.

I'd hoped it would be as simple as:

```
firebase.query['first_name']
=> 'Fred'
```

Could someone please explain how I might go about querying Firebase with a `key` and returning the `value`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

colinta here!  You'll need to attach an observer (https://github.com/colinta/motion-firebase#attaching-observers-to-read-data).

`firebase_ref.once(:value) { |snapshot| snapshot.value }`

See https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios-api/Classes/FDataSnapshot.html for info on the `FDataSnapshot` type.

Comment: do you know if there's a way to get the value of a single key. Or in other words query Firebase with a single key?

Comment: Yes, `firebase_ref` doesn't have to be the root ref, it can be any url.  e.g. `username_ref = root_ref['user'][id]['username']`.  Then if you are listening for "change" events, you'll only hear about changes to `/user/[id]/username`.